# remove duplicate values generated from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Two array : **Fee** and **Amount**, have been formed as below based on **MYSQL JOIN Clause** and Table structure.

**Array Fee**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Annual Fee-Disability Scholarship
    [1] => Annual Fee-First rank Scholarship
    [2] => Monthly Fee-First rank Scholarship
)
```

**Array Amount**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000-20
    [1] => 1000-10
    [2] => 560-5
)
```

**Array Fee** contains the category of fee **And** assigned scholarship to each category

**Array Amount** contains the fee rate **And** the assigned scholarship percentage in each fee category.

I need to remove fee category and it's amount if this is already echoed.

Normally, using following PHP code:

```
$cat = array('Annual Fee-Disability Scholarship','Annual Fee-First rank Scholarship','Monthly Fee-First rank Scholarship');
$amount = array('1000-20','1000-10','560-5');
foreach (array_combine($cat, $amount) as $cat => $amount){
    $cat_ry = explode('-', $cat);
    $amount_ry = explode('-', $amount);

    $fee_cat = $cat_ry[0]; 
    $fee = $amount_ry[0];
    $sch_cat = $cat_ry[1];
    $sch = $amount_ry[1];

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$fee_cat</td>
            <td>$fee</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$sch_cat</td>
            <td>$sch</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

following table format is echoed.

[PHP Fiddle - complete code and result](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/pN)

[image]

Here Annual Fee category is being duplicated, cause two scholarships has been associated with this fee category.

So my requirement is to remove duplicate fee category and its related amount. **Required Output**

[image]

**So I try**: not echo fee category if it is already echoed

```
$fee_cat = "";
//code
//...
if($cat_ry[0] != $fee_cat){
    $fee_cat = $cat_ry[0];
    //code
    //...
}
```

but here, with duplicated fee category another scholarship **First Rank Scholarship** is also removed

[PHP Fiddle - complete code and result](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/pM)

[image]

Comment: You rely a lot on the order of items in the arrays. Your (updated) if statement will break if the order is Annual, monthly, annual. It's fine for now, but just giving you some food for thought :) Same issue of course for using array_combine, but I don't know the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get expected result by separating echo output.
PHP Fiddle: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/pP

```
$cat = array('Annual Fee-Disability Scholarship','Annual Fee-First rank Scholarship','Monthly Fee-First rank Scholarship');
$amount = array('1000-20','1000-10','560-5');

$outputed_fee_cat = [];
foreach (array_combine($cat, $amount) as $cat => $amount){
    $cat_ry = explode('-', $cat);
    $amount_ry = explode('-', $amount);

    $fee = $amount_ry[0];
    $sch_cat = $cat_ry[1];
    $sch = $amount_ry[1];
    $fee_cat = $cat_ry[0];
    if (!in_array($fee_cat, $outputed_fee_cat)) {
        $outputed_fee_cat[] = $fee_cat;

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='bold'>$fee_cat</td>
            <td>$fee</td>
        </tr>";
    }
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$sch_cat</td>
            <td>$sch</td>
        </tr>";
}
```